# Print out rounded floating point number in MIPS

Tags: mips

I am not sure how to print out a floating point single with one decimal place.

I get '88.09999847' instead of '88.1'. Please advise

For example:  if I have register $f10 = '88.09999847'

```
mov.s   $f12,   $f10

li  $v0,    2   

syscall
```

I get output as "88.09999847"

How do I round up to one decimal place and print out "88.1"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: +1 for a good question. I think the answer will involve bitmasking in the mantissa portion of the float, but I can't remember the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

1) Multiply the number by 10 (since you're rounding to one decimal place.)
2) Push the number to the stack (or appropriate register.)
3) Round is a system call (on my machine, the code is `call roundf`)
4) Divide the result by 10